# Video.js source not in Apache folder

Tags: linux, html, apache, video, video.js

I have an Apache Server running on linux

The directory used for the website is the default
/var/www

When Using Video.js, setting the video source is easy when the files are in the same directory.
e.g. 
`/var/www/index.html`
`/var/www/video/video1.mp4`

`<source src="video/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />`

I can't seem to set this source if the files are not in the Apache folder however.
e.g.

`/home/user/video/video2.mp4`
`<source src="/home/user/video/video2.mp4" type='video/mp4' />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apache is using /var/www as your root, I don't think it will allow access to anything outside of that directory. Have you tried accessing those files directly in a browser, outside of video.js?

Additionally, by setting the source URL to '/home/user/video/video2.mp4', you're telling the browser to look for the file at "www.mywebsite.com/home/user/video/video2.mp4', which apache will translate to "/var/www/home/user/video/video2.mp4".

I'm far from an expert on how Apache works, but I hope that helps.

Comment: My thoughts are the same, but I hoped I was mistaken.